# Can't use INNER JOIN on 2 DataTables in a DataSet - Tables don't see each other - C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a DataSet called DataSet1. This is how it looks like (all column names which are important for this question are revealed, unimportant ones are hidden):

[image]

I've been trying to add a query on the Projects table just like that (it's the bottom row of the upper Projects table, Abfrage hinzufügen means add query):

[image]

[image]

But it says that the object dbo.Timerecord is invalid. Why can't 2 datatables in the same dataset see each other and how can I change that?

Comment: You can use the designer(Abfrage-Generator) and choose the related table from the dropdownlist, then the join is created automatically

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Do they both link to the same database?

Comment: No. Is that a problem?